# Is there a misinterpretation of NIST data, in this conclusion about the order of 4s and 3d, in neutral scandium, contradicting HF calculations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

Is there a misinterpretation of NIST data, in this conclusion about the order of 4s and 3d, that contradicts Hartree Fock calculations?

I understand that it is a clear conclusion based on Hartree Fock calculations, that for neutral Potassium and neutral Calcium, 4s is lower than 3d, as per afbau. And that for neutral scandium, the 4s and 3d switch and 3d becomes lower than 4s. That's mentioned in [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed071p469), and I understand that it's well established and not disputed.

Something i've seen that contradicts that conclusion about 4s and 3d, is [this article](http://tinyurl.com/yhp36hns) by Geoffrey Neuss. There, in Figure 3, he shows this graph, which seems to differ with HF calculations, on neutral scandium.

[image]

There Neuss (I suppose controversially), has 4s and 3d in afbau order, so 4s below 3d, for neutral scandium.

And from what I understand, the way Neuss got the 138 kJ/mol figure for neutral scandium, is going to the [NIST website](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html) searching "Sc 0", to get it to show data on neutral scandium, which shows [this page](http://tinyurl.com/yhp36hns)

[image]

From there he's picked the ~11500 cm^-1  figure, [doing a unit conversion](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/oc/martin/tools/hartree.html) that gives 138 kJ/mol

Is that, in Neuss's article, a misinterpretation of the NIST data?

I have heard that one cannot conclude order of 3d and 4s sublevels, from NIST data. And, that's besides the fact that the order of 3d and 4s sublevels is well established by HF calculations to be 3d below 4s, for neutral scandium.